# Swift: Set/Add Label color for files shown in finder

Tags: swift, colors, label, finder

I want to set a colored label for files my app already processed (in Swift), which is shown by the finder. But I don't even know an exact search term. "Label" and "color" always take me to UI parts of OSX.
So any tipps where to get such information?

Addition:
I found the discussion about localized color names. Now I'm able to set or remove the label, but only because I guessed the correct localized strings. Any idea, if there is a function or translation table? I know the few german and english names, but will get problems for the chinese ones. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324886/setresourcevalue-nsurltagnameskey-error (the question is a bit different but the answer should help you achieve this task).