# Retrieving Finder tags from within a Swift or Objective-C app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, finder

Using `NSURL` APIs, how can a I determine which tags are set on a directory?  The only API I'm aware of does indeed return a number associated with tags, but I'm not sure how to extract the specific tags from the returned value.

For example this will return `4` for directory `B`.  I need to determine that both `Blue` and `Green` tags are set.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Username/Desktop/Test/B")
let resourceValues = try! url.resourceValues(forKeys: 
      [URLResourceKey.labelNumberKey])
print(resourceValues.labelNumber!) // 4
```

[image]

I've seen some use an `enum` to map the results back to Swift, but this doesn't seem to handle multiple tags.

```
enum LabelColor: Int {
    case none
    case gray
    case green
    case purple
    case blue
    case yellow
    case red
    case orange
}
```

So it seems an `OptionSet` would be the best implementation here for Swift.

If someone can point me to the algorithm used to extract tags from the total number that would be great!

Comment: Look at the `tagNamesKey`

Comment: @vadian This returns the localized tag names as strings.  I was hoping to use the numeric values to make it more robust when running under different locales. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719432/swift-3-set-finder-label-color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to grab the numeric values to the tags other than [through a shell](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/10/31/finder-tags-commonplace-metadata/).

However, you can, as @Martin-R suggested, get an array of the tags attached to the file. I think this is best because user's can create custom tags, which may be hard to identify numerically.

I would suggest getting the array by using ⤵︎

```swift
var itemTags: [String] = []
do {
    let resources = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.tagNamesKey])
    if let tags = resources.tagNames {
        itemTags = tags // ["Green", "Red"]
    }
} catch {}
```

Once you have the array then you can just use some kind of enum & switch, for loop, or if/else to match it to colours you designate yourself.

#### Secret Sauce ⤵︎

Now the problem is that if you're sandboxed and you try this you'll probably only get one tag I imagine. It'll be the front-most tag.

This is just another one of Apple's security measures. **To get around this your sandbox needs to extend to this resource.**

It's a bit much to get into security scopes in this post, but here are two things you could try.

1. Use `NSOpenPanel()` to get the url or parent directory url. This will automatically give you privileges to that resource for that session. You can bookmark it, resolve it, [and start accessing it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso).
2. Stop using the sandbox

Unfortunately, I don't know of other solutions that would work. I chose the first and it's the least painful at the moment.