# How to add a Finder tag in macOS programmatically using Swift without tagging a file?

Tags: swift, macos, metadata, xattr

I'm building a macOS app which programmatically sets Finder tags for files using extended attributes similar to this answer for [Swift 3: Set Finder label color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40314367/3439314). This works well.
However, I'd like to create a tag and make it available in the filesystem without having to add the tag to a particular file. For example, when the user clicks a button, I want to create a tag, similar to *Finder - Preferences - Tags*, where you can create a new tag by pressing the + button. You don't have to specify a file or folder.

I tried adding a new tag to *_kMDItemUserTags* of a dummy folder using the [setResourceValue API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1413819-setresourcevalue). This creates the tag as expected. However, the dummy folder now shows up in the search for this tag, which is not nice. As soon as I remove the tag from the dummy folder again (and no other file or folder has this tag) the tag is gone from the list of available tags.

So, I wonder how is it possible to create a new tag in Swift and persist it without assigning it to a file?

Comment: Related: [List all tags in Terminal in Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112388/list-all-tags-in-terminal-in-mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research on the subject recently when asked for tagging support being added to my "SDview" image viewer/organizer, and it seems that those tags do not have any storage, where you could add/persist them "for later use". The list of available tags is a dynamic construct built from Spotlight metadata aggregating tags already used. IOW if you want your tag to show up in the list of available tags - you have to have it assigned to something.